# Regular expression to add a prefix in all the cell name in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, html

I am simulating MS excel in javascript.
I have to add a prefix in all the cellname present in the formula.
Eg.

```
 AB75*(AA79+A9)+A2*A5
```

What I want to add a prefix (lets say X) in all the cellnames

Output should be

```
X.AB75*(X.AA79+X.A9)+X.A2*X.A5
```

How can I achieve this with regular expression.

> > I want to add X to only cellname in which "." in not added .
> >     Eg.

```
AB75*(Y.AA79+A9)+Z.A2*A5
```

should result into

```
X.AB75*(Y.AA79+X.A9)+Z.A2*X.A5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this:

```
formula.replace(/(^|[^.A-Z])([A-Z]+\d+)/g, "$1X.$2");
```

it will match any upper case letters followed by numbers but not if there are dots before the letters.

Answer (score 1):

```
formula.replace(/([A-Z]+\d+)/g, "X.$1")
```

Here we assume that a cell name is defined as *one or more capital letters (`[A-Z]+`), followed by one or more digits (`\d+`)*. From there, we just prefix the occurrences with `X.` Note that the `g` flag is used to find all matches.

---

**Update:** As javascript regexes lack some niceties (like lookbehind), it will be hard to do it with a single regex. Here is one alternative solution:

```
var parts = formula.split(/(?=[^.\w])/);

var reconstructedFormula = parts.map(function(part) { 
  if(part.indexOf('.') !== -1)
    return part;
  else
    return part.replace(/([A-Z]+\d+)/g, "X.$1");
}).join();
```

Comment: AB75*Balance_sheet.AA79  I want to add X only for AB75 . not the one starts from "."